# Silently open a web browser using Java code

Tags: java, process, silent

I'm trying to figure out how to open a web browser silently in Java. Silently meaning that the user has no idea that it opens unless they look in the task manager. I am trying to get some things to load in the cache for the web browser to be able to manipulate the files that are in the cache but don't want to interrupt the user's experience. I am open to working with different browsers, but am currently using chrome.

Right now I am experimenting with

```
    Desktop.getDesktop().open("Html File Here");
```

but it just opens the browser window. This is an issue because it opens a tab in an already running browser so I also run into an issue where I can not close it safely after I am done.

Basically, I need to load data into the cache from a browser but don't want the user to be interrupted.

Comment: You won't find a way to do this.

Comment: @bmargulies ok, do you know of any way i can open things such as soundcloud links in a java application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking around for something similar before and stumbled upon [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) which is what Play! framework uses for its testing.

Have a look at it and let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: I don't think Selenium will cache anything to the user's browser, if that's what OP wants. Selenium's cache and users web browser cache will be independent.

Comment: This might work, I don't necessarily need it in the browser's cache but somewhere temporarily on the computer. I'll take a look! thanks